# Which Microsoft database is the most logical use case for financial data?

Tags: database, winforms

Im looking through all the options in Visual Studio for database integratiion with Winforms apps. I am just overwhelmed by the options. It's not that I can't read about each of them on MSDN which I have done, it's that most of them seem adequate. Basically I have a fairly large collection of financial data which I need to stuff into a db an run queries on it from a Windows Form. Can someone briefly advice which of Service Based Databas, ADO.Net and all it's varients, Local Database, SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Databace, Service Based Database etc would be suited to the task? Or just generally if any of them are NOT suited at all?

Comment: About how much data (KB? GB?) and how many users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use SQL Server Express, which is a free version of SQL Server.
Why? it has very good tools and will grow and scale-up very easily, whether you wish to add more (large volumes) of data, or support multiple front-ends - ASP.NET, mobile, Winforms, MVC, MS Access.

You may wish to connect to your SQL Server back-end with Access to run ad-hoc queries and generate quick reports off of them and at the same time keep expose your data through services via .NET.  SQL Server will support all these front-ends at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are variants of SQL Server. Just create the database in whatever manner you like, and use Entity Framework (or at worse, classic ADO.NET) to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking other specific requirements and assuming your data is less than the 10GB limit for the free [SQL Server 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx).  If you find that you need to store more than 10GB, or evolve to use other features of SQL Server, the upgrade path is very straightforward.

Entity Framework is generally a very productive way to access the database from WinForms.  If you're not familiar with it, I would recommend setting aside some time to learn to use it if you can.  You will quickly make up the time invested in productivity gains.